# How can I modify my UNIX prompt to show the name of the current branch?

Tags: macos, git, command-line, prompt

I want to modify my shell prompt so that it show the name of the current branch. Is there any easy way to do it?

(For information, I'm using Bash on Mac OS X.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a third-party tool: Git already provides a [shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/563d4e59bd167fe2eecc5480e3841d878b1c8c2b/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) for adding the current branch name (if any) to your shell prompt; it's compatible with both `bash` and `zsh`.

Simply download that script, and then follow the installation instructions:

> 1. Copy this file to somewhere (e.g. `~/.git-prompt.sh`).
> 2. Add the following line to your `.bashrc/.zshrc`:
>
>    ```
>    source ~/.git-prompt.sh
>    ```
> 3. Change your PS1 to call `__git_ps1` as command-substitution:
>
>    - Bash: `PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '`
>    - ZSH:  `setopt PROMPT_SUBST ; PS1='[%n@%m %c$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '`
>
>    the optional argument will be used as format string.

You might prefer a more lightweight prompt than the one given; for example, I've set mine to

```
export PS1='\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\$ '
```

instead.

Finally, relaunch Terminal (or source `~/.bash_profile`, since you're using `bash`) and you're good to go:

[image]

Comment: @joan Yes; the value assigned to `PS1` doesn't have to be exactly that given in the installation instructions (I've set mine to `PS1='\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\$ '`), but it has to contain `$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")` somewhere; otherwise, your branch won't appear in your prompt.

Comment: Thanks, just waht I needed ! Just for the record, in my case the bash line is: export PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BashIt](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) which is a bundle of a loooot of useful things (including git branching display) as shown below: [image]